# Are there published specifications of Chrome Remote Desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, security, remote-desktop, google-chrome-extensions, remote

Specifically, I'm trying to find security and encryption information, and I can not seem to find the security protocols. I'd like to compare it to others such as TeamViewer and Screens.

Comment: Like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Features

Comment: I saw the wikipedia page, but there isn't any detail. Here's an example from TeamViewer that i'm looking for with Chrome Remote Desktop: https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/trust-center/security/